# Unable to select item from combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I've implemented `ActionListener` so that my ship list changes according to the nation and ship type, but the problem is that I can't select any ships.

Any idea(s) on where I may have went wrong?

```
private class ShipNameListener implements ActionListener
{   
    public ShipNameListener()
    {
        view.setShipNameListener(this);
    }   

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {           
        if (view.getNationComboBox().getSelectedItem() == "USA")
        {
            if (view.getShipTypeComboBox().getSelectedItem() == "Battleship")
            {
                view.setShipList(lists.getUSABattleships());
            }
            else if (view.getShipTypeComboBox().getSelectedItem() == "CV")
            {
                view.setShipList(lists.getUSACVs());
            }
            else if (view.getShipTypeComboBox().getSelectedItem() == "Destroyer")
            {
                view.setShipList(lists.getUSADestroyers());
            }
            else if (view.getShipTypeComboBox().getSelectedItem() == "Cruiser")
            {
                view.setShipList(lists.getUSACruisers());
            }
        }           
    }       
}
```

Above is said `ActionListener` in Controller class.

```
public void setShipNameListener(ActionListener al) 
{
    comboBoxNation.addActionListener(al);
    comboBoxShipType.addActionListener(al);
    comboBoxShipName.addActionListener(al);     
}
```

Above is setter in View class.

[image: Can't select other items from combobox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `==` for Object comparisons. You only use `==` for primitive comparisons.

For Objects use the `equals(...)` method.

Comment: damn! You were fast I was about to post the same answer

Comment: Oh yeah I totally forgot about using equals(...) for Strings.

Comment: Well it still didn't solve the problem. I still can't select any ships :(

Comment: Then you need to step through the logic to determine why the code is not executing as you expect. Either use a debugger or start adding System.out.printnln(...) statements to see the logic flow.